# Why startAt() query function returns all data regardless?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

My Realtime DB node structure is as below:

```
Bookings{
      carID1{ 
        BookingStartTime: some POJO
        BookingStartTime: some POJO
        --
        --
       }
 }
```

[image]

N.B: BookingStartTime is a long.

I want to query the carID node in order to return all the bookings in ascending order + return bookings that have BookingStartTime>= a given value.

My code does the sorting in ascending order, but totally ignores the startAt() query function and returns all nodes under that CarID.

Here's my code:

```
mBookingsNodeReference.child("carID1").orderByValue().startAt(Here i put 
some long number).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          //I get the objects                  
    }
}
```

A sample of a real BookingStartTime from my DB under "carID1" is: 1564221600000

And when I query using startAt(1564223789000), it is also returned.

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add a screenshot of it.

Comment: @AlexMamo I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to order/filter based on the **key** of each node. In that case you should use `orderByKey()`, not `orderByValue()`.

So:

```
mBookingsNodeReference.child("carID1").orderByKey().startAt(...)
```